# Efficient methods of modifying a Delaunay triangulation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry, computational-geometry, delaunay

MATLAB states on [their website](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-editing-delaunay-triangulations.html):

> It is more efficient to edit a delaunayTriangulation to make minor modifications as opposed to recreating a new delaunayTriangulation from scratch

Are there any algorithms for this?

If I have 1000 points and move 3 of them to new locations, would the best method be to remove them and reinsert them, or is there a better way?

Comment: The early algorithm of Green and Sibson works incrementally, i.e. by adding the points one after another. Though it is inefficient to create a whole diagram from scratch, it could make sense for local additions. I suspect that it could be possible to "reverse" it to implement deletions, but this is just an impression. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By_VJMXKVXk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a whole family of algorithms for constructing a Delaunay triangulation by inserting points one at a time.  And there's a pretty good algorithm for removing points described by Devillers, O. (2002). "On deletion in Delaunay triangulations", International Journal of Computational Geometry * Applications 12.3.  You should be able to find a couple of different versions of Devillers' article on the web.

Since you're working in MATLAB, this won't help you much but I have implemented Devillers' algorithm in Java and it works quite well.  If you have an API that supports modifying an existing triangulation, then removing 3 points and then inserting them someplace else in the mesh should happen so fast that it would be hard to measure the time required for the operation.  Of course, 1000 vertices is a pretty small triangulation, and the time required to simply rebuild the mesh should also be quite small.  So unless you are doing that many, many times, it should be reasonable to simply rebuild the mesh each time you need to change its content.

If you would like to see a Java-based implementation of an incremental Delaunay triangle implementation, you can find one at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour.   I've written up some notes on the implementation details and posted them at http://gwlucastrig.github.io/Tinfour/doc/TinfourAlgorithmsAndDataElements.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer! (I would upvote it if I had enough reputation) I'm surprised I didn't find those resources before because I did try looking around.

Comment: I'm been looking through the source code of Tinfour, and I've noticed that the triangulation is represented with edges instead of triangles. Would it be feasible to implement an algorithm that uses triangles instead of edges?

Comment: Support for triangles is already implemented. If you go to the Tinfour wiki, you'll find an article about using the TriangleCollector class at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/Tutorial-Using-TriangleCollector-Techniques  Triangles can also be constructed from edges dynamically as described in https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/Tutorial-Using-Edge-Based-Techniques-Part-1

Comment: From your comments, it looks like you were able to follow the Tinfour code pretty well. And that was a good observation on your part recognizing the role of edges in the implementation. One of my early versions of the project used triangles as the fundamental geometric construct rather than edges, but it turned out that edges have a lot of advantages in terms of storage size and flexibility.

Comment: I guess it does make sense that edges are a better structure for storing the triangulation. Your work has really given me a head start in understanding Delaunay triangulations, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, one last question: is it possible to implement an observer on edge insertions and removals? I'm looking for a way to easily keep track of triangles.

Comment: There's nothing built into the existing code, but you can always create a derived class that overrides the add and remove methods and makes them invoke an observer. I'm a little busy at work right now, but if you sent me an outline of what you're trying to accomplish, I might be able to send you some example code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In my use case, I need to modify around 3-5 of 1500 points and then reaccess the triangles. I've been further looking at Tinfour's source, and it seems that it's pretty optimized for inserting a lot of points, but less so for accessing triangles themselves. Right now, I'm just trying to think of ways to keep track of triangles so I don't have to use a TriangleCollector each time the points are modified.

Comment: I've just done some benchmarks on your library against CGAL, and your implementation appears to be 8x faster! This is pretty surprising, considering I used C++ for CGAL and it has gone through many optimizations over the past 2 decades.

Comment: Pleased to hear about the performance. Tinfour was designed to handle the large vertex sets found in Lidar samples, so speed was an important consideration.  In terms of getting triangles near an insertion point, you can use edge techniques.     INeighborEdgeLocator locator = tin.getNeighborEdgeLocator();
      IQuadEdge edge = locator.getNeigborEdge(0.5, 0.5);  // coordinates of interest
      for(IQuadEdge e: edge.pinwheel()){
          Vertex A = e.getA();
          Vertex B = e.getB();
          Vertex C = e.getForward().getB(); // may be null
      }

Comment: Once you've got a neighboring edge using the edge locator, you can construct triangles by using the pinwheel() method to iterate through the connected edges. This process is described on the Tinfour wiki article https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/Tutorial-Using-Edge-Based-Techniques-Part-1   One caveat, watch out for null vertices (ghost vertices) if the iteration goes outside of the triangulation.  In my earlier code example, vertex C could be a null vertex reference, but not A or B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. For example, you can find an algorithm in [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1056738) (Dynamic Voronoi Diagrams) to update a given Delaunay triangulation (DT) in `O(n)` for each deletion or insertion. As the time complexity of constructing a DT is in `O(n log(n))`, absolutely updating the current DT is much faster in terms of the order of magnitude.